# Using R dplyr throws error

Tags: r, statistics, package, dplyr

I am learning to use the dplyr pkg.

```
library(dplyr)
```

A toy dataset:

```
d <- expand.grid("id"=1:3,"x1"=10:12,"x2"=(20:22))
```

Later I may need to loop through the columns, my real data has 30K rows, 70 columns

```
i <- 2
```

here I am hoping to use a generic variable name

```
my.variable <- names(d[i])
my.variable
```

A function to normalize each group to the range 0-1

```
norm <- function(x) (x - min(x,na.rm = TRUE))/(max(x,na.rm = TRUE)-min(x,na.rm = TRUE))

df.out <- d %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(x.norm = norm(get(my.variable, envir = as.environment(d))))
```

throws an error:

```
Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1
```

Any help appreciated as to the reason for the error. Also, is this a viable way of doing this normalizing task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you really want the columns as in @James' answer. Here as I understand your question:

```
d %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_each(funs(norm(.)))

Groups: id

   id  x1  x2
1   1 0.0 0.0
2   2 0.0 0.0
3   3 0.0 0.0
```

...

Comment: Thanks Dieter! A superb and economical solution! I have given your solution some stress tests with 33K rows and 73 columns: processed in less than 2 seconds on an ageing laptop. Exceeded all my expectations.

Comment: Praise is to Hadley. The previous `ddplyr` was a great concept, but slow. So the restart in `dplyr` was worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the use of `get`, which I'm sure is a breach of the @hadley license agreement ;)

To evaluate character arguments, you can use `mutate_each_q`. However, when using a single function, it will overwrite the variable, so you must use two functions and drop the second variable afterwards:

```
d %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_each_q(funs(x.norm=norm, identity),my.variable) %>%
      select(-identity)
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: id

  id x1 x2 x.norm
1  1 10 20    0.0
2  2 10 20    0.0
3  3 10 20    0.0
4  1 11 20    0.5
5  2 11 20    0.5
6  3 11 20    0.5
...
```

Comment: +1 for hadley license agreement. However, `mutate_each_q` is depracated, and `head` is implicit in `tbl_df`, i.e. results from `dplyr` (slightly simplified).

Comment: Kudos to Hadley Wickham! James, thanks for your input and a couple of ideas that were new to me.